# Reading the SAS dataset with user-defined formats in .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sas

I've been asked to read the SAS dataset in an ASP.Net application. This dataset contains the date variable as well as the variables with user-defined formats. 
These variables is displayed in the numeric format in the grid columns.
How to display the SAS formats that assigned to the SAS dataset?

Comment: How are you displaying it right now - without formats?  What code are you  using?

Comment: The returned data doesn't have any of SAS formats applied. E.g. the date variable is displayed as a numeric variable. I use C# to read the SAS dataset in the ADODB recorset. I found that I should use a a Format Service workspace utilities to apply SAs formats to the data returned. Does anyone have an example of the code?

Comment: Thanks. I got the answer from the SAS support.

Comment: could you post the answer?

Answer (score 0):

In order to have the formats applied you should:

1. Open Connection object
2. Create a custom property for this connection object (SAS Formats) that tells ADO how to deal with SAS formats (obRecordset.Properties("SAS Formats")="*ALL*")
3. Assign a libref for the format catalog

See the answer on the page 92-96 "Reading User-Defined SAS Formats and Informat" section of the [SAS 9.3 Providers for OLE DB Cookbook](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/oledbpr/63701/PDF/default/oledbpr.pdf)